# Create a Vector[Vector[Char]] from a file

Tags: scala

I'm a newbie, trying to read a file and create a Vector[Vector[Char]].  Each line of the file should result in a different vector.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
val empty: Vector[Vector[Char]]       = Vector()
lazy val lines: List[String]          = Source.fromFile("test.txt").getLines.toList
lazy val vecList: List[Vector[Char]]  = lines.map(str => Vector(str: _*))
lazy val vector: Vector[Vector[Char]] = vecList.foldRight(empty) (_ +: _)
```

The file will never be large, so scalability isn't an issue.  The above code seems to work, but I feel like it's going all around the barn.  Is there a simpler, more direct way to do this?

Comment: As a side note: Is there a particular reason you need a `Vector`? It's more idiomatic in Scala only to specify the collection type that has the performance characteristics you need—i.e., probably `IndexedSeq` in this case—not the implementation.

Comment: @Travis. I just finished Martin Odersky's Coursera course in Scala, and I'm trying to extend one of the assignments.  That assignment used a Vector, so I'm sticking with it.  Unfortunately, the course had no file I/O, so I'm trying to learn some of that, too.

Comment: Thanks everyone who answered.  These are all certainly are more concise than what I came up with.  It's going to take me a little while to wrap my head around some of them.  I haven't installed Scala 2.10 yet, but that "to" method looks very attractive.

Answer (score 5):

The following is a solution using Scala 2.10:

```
source.getLines.to[Vector].map(_.to[Vector])
```

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in a comment above, it's more idiomatic to use `IndexedSeq` in cases where you need to be able to grab an element at a particular index in constant time. The current default implementation of `IndexedSeq` is `Vector`, so if you write the following:

```
val xs = IndexedSeq(1, 2, 3)
```

You'll actually get a `Vector[Int]` behind the scenes, but that's just an implementation detail, since it's statically typed as a `IndexedSeq[Int]`. If a new, more performant default implementation is introduced in the future, you'll benefit from the change for free.

Using `IndexedSeq` also allows you to write this operation very concisely without relying on Scala 2.10's new `to` method. Assuming we have a source `s` that we're opening and closing elsewhere, this is all you need:

```
val lines: IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[Char]] = s.getLines.map(wrapString).toIndexedSeq
```

Where `wrapString` is a method provided by [`scala.Predef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef%24.html) to support treating strings as sequences of characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.io.Source
```

2.9 or earlier:

```
Vector() ++ Source.fromFile("test.txt").getLines.map(Vector() ++ _)
```

2.10 and after:

```
Source.fromFile("test.txt").getLines.map(_.to[Vector]).to[Vector]
```

(Map on the iterator first so you don't have to create the vector twice.)

Answer (score 0):

A little improvement, avoiding `foldLeft()`:

```
Vector(Source.fromFile("test.txt").getLines.toSeq: _*) map {l => Vector(l: _*)}
```

However remember you actually have to close `Source.fromFile("test.txt")` object.